# VBA Excel copy comment including formatting

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm using Excel 2007, and trying to write a VBA subroutine that will copy cell comments (including formatting). Cell comments can contain basic text formatting (style eg. bold etc) and I can successfully copy the text, but can't find a way to bring the formatting with it.

I was hoping I could simply define a Comments object, then set it, but no go:

```
Sub TestCommentCopy()

Dim r As Range
Dim c As Comment
Set r = Selection

If (Not r.Areas(1).Comment Is Nothing) Then
    Set c = r.Areas(1).Comment
End If

'Set r(1, 2).Comment = c ' Object error
'   r(1, 2).Comment = c  'Object error
'   Set r(1,2).Comment = c ' Object error
r(1, 2).ClearComments ' Works
'   r(1, 2).AddComment c 'Does not work - requires text only

r(1, 2).AddComment c.Text 'Works, but only get plain text, no formatting

End Sub
```

Is there a way in Excel to copy one cell's comment to another, including the formatting, not just the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy formatted comments:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("E9").Copy
    Range("L3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah thanks Gary's student - I can use the PasteSpecial method with the xlPasteComments to get the whole thing (value and format) in the copy...thanks again. Not sure whether using the method in my code was invalid, or a Microsoft foible with the object model, but in any case, it didn't work.